# ATI graphics problem

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

I am using HP Compaq 6735b laptop and it comes with a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3200 Graphics card. I have recently installed 12.04 on it.

Can someone tell me how will I know if the Graphics card is working or not?

Comment: it would be nice if you write correct title.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting > System Information and will be displayed common specs information consits of OS architecture, processor, gpu, hardrive and memory.

Other way

Go to the terminal : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then type : `lspci | grep VGA`

Finally will be displayed information of your running VGA.

Actually Ubuntu is bundled with open source AMD Accelerated Graphics driver and going to automatically run when Ubuntu detecting AMD Radeon on your board. if it's not successful, will automatically be directed to BIOS VGA. It's indicated by display that displaying low resolution 800 x 600.

Answer (score -1):

Run the Additional Drivers program and it will show you 3rd party drivers available for your Ati graphics card and whether they are enabled or not.

Note: Sometimes enabling the Ati graphics from this front-end does not always work, so if you are one of the unlucky ones then do this:

Open Terminal and type each of the 3 lines separately and hit enter:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo aticonfig --initial
fglrxinfo
```

The last command should bring up something similar to this:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series       
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Now reboot and all should be working well.